# From within Fortran program, check if compiled with "-g"

Tags: debugging, fortran, gfortran

I'm hoping to add some additional info logging if a program gets compiled the debug flag, `-g`. I'm using gfortran (although I think `-g` is ubiquitous). Stepping through the program, in this case, would be especially tedious in gdb. In particular, I'm hoping something like:

```
if (compiledwithg()) then
    print *, extraNiceInfo
endif
```

I know in C programs people usually would use stuff like `#ifdef DEBUG`, then print some additional info. As far as I know, there's no similar feature in Fortran. Does anyone know of anything like this?

Comment: You can often [get details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46464763/3157076) of how a program was complied.

Comment: The ifdef DEBUG can be uses in Fortran as well! Just enable the preprocessor. The reason for it is to not even compile those if checks, when not using them.

Comment: @Gavin : What about creating a source file with the function `compiled_with_g()` that returns always true ? If some source files are to be compiled with `-g` and some other aren't, what about creating a rule in the make file that generates this function per source file basis ? But using the preprocessor are proposed by @Vladimir, surely is the best solution

Comment: A function is not necessary, a global constant is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question as it was asked: yes, it is now possible in modern versions of Fortran to know which options were used for compiling. As linked by francescalus, the `COMPILER_OPTIONS()` subroutine is the way to go.

```
  use iso_fortran_env

  logical :: compiled_with_g
  character(:), allocatable :: options

  options = compiler_options()

  compiled_with_g =  index(options, "-g") > 0

  print *, compiled_with_g
end
```

and

```
> gfortran-7 compiled_with_g.f90
> ./a.out 
 F
> gfortran-7 -g compiled_with_g.f90
> ./a.out 
 T
```

*Note, it will trigger true on any compiler option that begins with `-g` or just contains substring `-g`. I tried using `" -g "`, but it is problematic when the string begins or ends with this option. You can also just add these two special cases to the if condition.*

---

You can use the `#ifdef DEBUG` everywhere and compile all sources with `-cpp` or `-fpp` (depending on the compiler).

---

Or you can define a global constant in a module

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  logical, parameter :: compiled_with_g  = .true.
#else
  logical, parameter :: compiled_with_g  = .false.
#endif
```

and compile just this module with `-cpp` or `-fpp`.

You can do the same with a function `compiledwithg()` and have the macro only in the function.

---

Or you can have two versions of this very small module:

```
module debug_mod
  logical, parameter :: debug = .true.
end module
```

and

```
module debug_mod
  logical, parameter :: debug = .false.
end module
```

and set your build system (like a Makefile) to use the right one. The compiler will then remove the dead code, if the parameter is false, so it is as efficient, as a macro.